# Discord.js Add a role to members with a specific role

Tags: discord.js

I wanted to make a command, that adds a role to members with a specific role.

**EXAMPLE**

i do the command !roleall

The commands finds members with the role "test123", and adds a role called "test111" to members who has that role.

**I tried this but didnt work:**

```js
       const Role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("981657701962629172");
    
message.guild.members.filter((role => role.name === '・Verified')).forEach(member => member.addRole(Role2))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to first fetch both the roles, then filter through all the members in the guild, check which member has the first role and then add the second role to them. We can fetch the roles by using `message.guild.roles.cache.get()` if you have the role id or `message.guild.roles.cache.find()` if you have the role name. Then, to filter through the members, we can use `message.guild.members.cache.forEach()` and then use `member.roles.cache.has(role-id)` to check if the member has the role. The code might look something like this:

```js
const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get('981657701962629172')
const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '・Verified')
message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => {
    if (member.roles.cache.has(role1.id)) {
        member.roles.add(role2)
    }
})
```